# How to prevent divs from moving when window resizes?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to stop these divs from moving up and down + side to side when the window resizes. 
Is there a way where the divs just stay in place and the window just crops the web when it's a smaller size?

I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to stop these divs from moving up and down + side to side when the window resizes. 
Is there a way where the divs just stay in place and the window just crops the web when it's a smaller size?

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("year");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.display === "block") {
      content.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      content.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
/*font*/
@font-face {
    font-family: 'coresansgs55mediuuploadedfile';
    src: url('../fonts/core_sans_gs_55_medium-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../fonts/core_sans_gs_55_medium-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono&display=swap');

/*background*/
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #FF76FB 0%, #C57BFF 35%, #00FFFB 100%);
    background-size: 200% 200%;
    animation: BackgroundGradient 20s ease infinite; 
    
}


@keyframes BackgroundGradient {
                0% {background-position: 0% 50%;}
                50% {background-position: 100% 50%;}
                100% {background-position: 0% 50%;}
}


/*content*/

h1 {    font-family: 'coresansgs55mediuuploadedfile';
        font-size: 100px;
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 50px;
        margin-top: 50px;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        margin: auto;
        z-index: 1;
        }
    
h1 a{color: #00FFD8;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1px blue;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px blue, 0px 0px blue, 3px 3px blue;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;}

h1 a:hover {color: #febfff;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1px magenta;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px magenta, 0px 0px magenta, 5px 4px magenta;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease; 
    letter-spacing: 10px;}
    

ul {
-webkit-animation: fadein 1s;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
  top: 250px;
  width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

li {
  display: inline;
    
    }    
    
li a {
    padding: 100px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'coresansgs55mediuuploadedfile';
    font-size: 30px;
    color: blue;
    width: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
}
    
li a:hover {
  color: magenta;
}


button { width: 100%; }
 [data-toggle="collapse"] {
    
color: blue;
font-family: 'Be Vietnam', sans-serif;
font-size: 50px;
 cursor: pointer;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 10px;
 background-color: transparent;
 border: none;
 margin-bottom: -1px;
 outline: none;
 -webkit-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
 transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
}

[data-toggle="collapse"]:hover {color: magenta; }
 [data-toggle="collapse"][aria-expanded="true"] {
 color: white;
 border: none;
}


.box {
    

  background-color: white;
text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid white;
  display: none;
  margin: 10px 20px 50px 20px;
padding: 0px 50px 50px 50px;

}

.box p { padding: 5px 20px; }

#work{
    padding-top: 25%;


}

.work1 {
    -webkit-animation: fadein 2s;

}

.work2 {
    -webkit-animation: fadein 3s;
}

.work3 {
    -webkit-animation: fadein 4s;

}

.work4 {
    -webkit-animation: fadein 5s;
}
@keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

p{
   font-family: 'Be Vietnam', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="work.css">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>
        
        
    </head>
    
    
    
        <body>
            
            
                <h1>
            <a href="../MAIN/main.html">HELLO</a> 
        </h1>

        <ul>
    <li><a href="../WORK/work.html"><font color="#ffffff">work</font></a></li>
  <li><a href="../ABOUT/about.html">about</a></li>
  <li><a href="../CONTACT/contact.html">contact</a></li>
        </ul>

        
        <div id="work">
            
        <div class="work1">
        <button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#box1" data-group="toggles" aria-expanded="false">
            WORK 1
        </button>
        </div>
        <div class="box" id="box1" aria-expanded="false">
            <p>
                WORK 1
            </p>
            
                
       
            
 
                
                
                </div>
        </div>
            
        <div class="work2">
          <button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#box2" data-group="toggles" aria-expanded="false">
            WORK 2
        </button>
            </div>
        <div class="box" id="box2" aria-expanded="false">
            <p>
                WORK 2
            </p>
        </div>
            
        <div class="work3">
        <button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#box3" data-group="toggles" aria-expanded="false">
            WORK 3
        </button>
            </div>
        <div class="box" id="box3" aria-expanded="false">
            <p>
               WORK 3
            </p>  
            

                </video>
        </div>
            
            
        </div>
            
        <div class="work4">
        <button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#box4" data-group="toggles" aria-expanded="false">
            WORK 4
        </button>
            </div>
            
        <div class="box" id="box4" aria-expanded="false">
            <p>
                WORK4
            </p>  
            

            
        </div>
            
            
            
        </div>
            
            
            
            
            
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script src="../WORK/work.js"></script>
        <script src="../JS/jquery.collapsible.js"></script>


        
        
    </body>
        
</html>
```

Comment: I see that your padding on your div#work css style is set to 25%, this will move your div up and down. You should use px instead of % if you want all elements to be static.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a ton of `padding` in order to center elements. You should instead use `margin: 0 auto` or (for headings or paragraphs) `text-align: center`. You also don't need to use `position: absolute` to move the content below the header at the top. Just give the header at the top a set height.

The padding set to 25% is taking up a ton of space and when the browser is made smaller the elements run out of space due to the padding.

Give the element containing HELLO a set height and a width of 100% instead of using padding and absolute positioning on the elements beneath it. Use `margin: auto 0` to center the Work elements. Get rid of the 25% padding and absolute positioning.

I added some background colors to the elements to make it easier to visualize what's going on.

[image]